# Update two fields in same document in MongoDB, where one field is simple update, other field is append to existing array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

A document in my MongoDB Collection has two fields which are

1. lastLongLat - `[123.45,11.34]` GeoJSON Point format
2. multipleLongLat - `[[12,45],[78,89],[12,54]]` GeoJSON MultiPoint format

An array newLongLat from Http Request is in this format : `newLongLat = [78.486671,17.385044];`
multipleLongLat already has array of arrays.
I need to update two fields as :

1. update lastLongLat to newLongLat
2. append newLongLat to existing data in multipleLongLat array at the end.

Document can be filtered by {"productId" : productId}.
I am using Mongoose framework with NodeJS. Please mention an efficient way to perform this operation simultaneously? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `$set` in an aggregation pipeline. You can simply treat the coordinates field as an inner field of an object.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "productId": "p1"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "lastLongLat": {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
          78.486671,
          17.385044
        ]
      },
      "multipleLongLat.coordinates": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$multipleLongLat.coordinates",
          [
            [
              78.486671,
              17.385044
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mZYn-bXxqfy)